# vercelでデプロイしたバージョン14のNext.jsにCSSを適用させたい

Tags: css, next.js

vercelへNext.jsのバージョンが14のExpressをデプロイしたときに、正しくCSSが反映されるようにするにはどうすれば良いかお伺いしたいです。

対象のgithubは以下です。
https://github.com/sunagi/dw
適用させたいCSSは/public/css/style.cssです。

vercelでデプロイされたサイトは以下です。
https://dw-eight.vercel.app/

この時、エラーメッセージとして以下のようにコンソールへ出力されます

```
dw-eight.vercel.app/:1 Refused to apply style from 'https://dw-eight.vercel.app/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```